# Landscape print mode on IE11

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer, printing, internet-explorer-10

I need to print an HTML page in landscape mode on Internet Explorer 11.

I tried:

```
<style type="text/css" media="print">
@page
{
    size: 11in 8.5in;
}
</style>
```

And

```
<style type="text/css" media="print">
@page
{
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}
</style>
```

But I can't achieve the landscape print. (on Chrome it is working fine).

How can I make this work?

Thanks, Nk

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by adding the following to your stylesheet, tested this in IE11.

```
@media print {
    @page {
        /*IE Landscape fix*/
        filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(Rotation=3);
    }
}
```